# Azure maps and Polygons

Tags: azure, maps, gis, azure-maps

Anyone know how to make Polygons when using Azure Maps?

I can't find any documentation on how to set them up, however, the Microsoft Blogs mention that Azure Maps support polygons

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I posted my question I found the answer

```
/* Create a rectangle */
var rectangle = new atlas.data.Feature(
  new atlas.data.Polygon([[
  [-73.98235, 40.76799],
  [-73.95785, 40.80044],
  [-73.94928, 40.7968],
  [-73.97317, 40.76437]
]]),
  {
  color: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
  outlineColor: "black",
  }
);
```

https://codepen.io/azuremaps/pen/yKbOvZ

Comment: That's a nice codepen example, but aren't you exposing your private subscription-key?